# How to add new and keep previous items in a generic List after each button click event?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I want to add new items to my generic list when user clicks on a button, but when i click the button,i seethat the the list contains only the last introduced item.
It seems that during each button click list get reinitialized.
How can i keep old items and add new items to my generic list and display all of them in the listbox?

Thank you..

**C# Code**

```
namespace Example
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for CreateProduct.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class CreateProduct : Window
   {
       public static float weight;
       public static int quantity;
       public static string customer, piece, material;

       public CreateProduct()
       {
            InitializeComponent();

       }

       public static List<Liste> AddList()
       {
            List<Liste> list = new List<Liste>();
            Liste kayit= new Liste();

            kayit.Customer = customer;
            kayit.Piece = piece;
            kayit.Material = material;
            kayit.Quantity = quantity;
            kayit.Weight = weight;

            list.Add(kayit);

            return list;        
       }

       private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
            customer = btnEditCustomer1.Text;
            piece = btnPiece.Text;
            material = txtMaterial.Text;
            quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);
            weight = float.Parse(txtWeight.Text);

            if (customer != null && piece != null && material != null)
            {
                listBoxProduct.ItemsSource = AddList();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Liste
    {
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public string Piece { get; set; }
        public string Material { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public float Weight { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

**XAML Code**

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listBoxProduct"  SelectionMode="Single"   Margin="0" Background="Transparent" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Height="200">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Height="30" CornerRadius="4" Width="875"  Background="#2E323B" BorderBrush="Black">
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Customer}"  Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="16"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Piece}"    Foreground="White"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="16"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Material}"  Foreground="White"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="16"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}"  Foreground="White"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="16"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Weight}"  Foreground="White"  TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="16"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: try using English as your class and Property names, It is kinda hard to understand which is which

Comment: It seems like you new to WPF (it's okay). But it can hard to understand all of advice what you get. So, I think you can better learning with "chat-mode" step by step. There is awesome [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf) for relative wpf (not only) discussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix a few issue with your code:

- avoid `static` when possible
- don't create a new instance of List on every click, you are loosing previous items. declare a field in a Window.
- listBox needs to know when new items are added to display them. but List doesn't report about additions/removals. use `ObservableCollection`

```
public partial class CreateProduct : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Liste> list = new ObservableCollection<Liste>();    

    public CreateProduct()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBoxProduct.ItemsSource = list;
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       float weight;
       int quantity;
       string customer, piece, material;

       customer = btnEditCustomer1.Text;
       piece = btnPiece.Text;
       material = txtMaterial.Text;
       quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);
       weight = float.Parse(txtWeight.Text);

       if (customer != null && piece != null && material != null)
       {
          Liste kayit = new Liste();

          kayit.Customer = customer;
          kayit.Piece = piece;
          kayit.Material = material;
          kayit.Quantity = quantity;
          kayit.Weight = weight;

          list.Add(kayit);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `AddList()` creates a new list on every button click. You have to create a new property for example:

```
public  ObservableCollection<Liste> AllItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Liste>();
```

and after that change your `AddList()`

```
public static Liste CreateItem()
{
    Liste kayit= new Liste();

    kayit.Customer = customer;
    kayit.Piece = piece;
    kayit.Material = material;
    kayit.Quantity = quantity;
    kayit.Weight = weight;

    return kayit;
}
```

and your `btnAdd_Click()` to

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    customer = btnEditCustomer1.Text;
    piece = btnPiece.Text;
    material = txtMaterial.Text;
    quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);
    weight = float.Parse(txtWeight.Text);

    if (customer != null && piece != null && material != null)
    {
        AllItems.Add( CreateItem() );
    }
}
```

So now `CreateItem()` your old `AddList()` will create a new item and this item will be added to your collection within the `btnAdd_Click` method.

Edit:

What I missed to say is that you have to set the `ItemSource` in the constructor.

```
public CreateProduct()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listBoxProduct.ItemsSource = AllItems;
}
```

---

SiteNote:

I would change your whole `btnAdd_Click` Method
to this:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string customer = btnEditCustomer1.Text;
    string piece = btnPiece.Text;
    string material = txtMaterial.Text;
    int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);
    float weight = float.Parse(txtWeight.Text);

    if (customer != null && piece != null && material != null)
    {
        var item = new Liste 
                       {
                           Customer = customer,
                           Piece = piece,
                           Material = material,
                           Quantity = quantity,
                           Weight = weight
                       };

        AllItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code is fully messed up.  Anyway, let me give a quick fix that will work for you.

```
static List<Liste> list = new List<Liste>();

public static List<Liste> ListeEkle()
{

    Liste kayit= new Liste();

    kayit.Musteri = musteri;
    kayit.Parca = parca;
    kayit.Malzeme = malzeme;
    kayit.Adet = Adet;
    kayit.Agirlik = Agirlik;

    list.Add(kayit);

    return list;


}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you my friend.But it doesnt work.It works only one time.But when i click the button,nothing happens else.

Comment: @Baris You have to remove the `list` creation from inside `ListeEkle` method an keep it outside of the method as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating the list with a single element inside it at every button click because the AddList method re-initializes the list (it creates a new List every time). The list needs to be created outside the AddList method (and outside of the button click event handler). Inside the AddList you're supposed to create an item (Liste) and just add it to the existing list, as pointed out by @Gopichandar's answer.

You might also want to consider using a (one-way) binding of the list to the listbox instead of recreating the listbox's ItemSource upon every click.

Comment: Thank you.I tried but I cant manage.Can you write more explanatory?